# Magento 1.9 - Add additional function after form validation fail

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to find the best place to add a function to fire whenever a form in magento is submitted and fails. By fail I mean a required field wasn't filled in properly.

Where would the best place be? Should I edit validation.js?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

It describes how to do it the proper way.